# unit-testing dll relying on 64-bit itk-framework

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, itk

I am trying to set up a "Native Unit Test Project" (Visual C++) that is testing a DLL-project which is based on the ITK framework. I will probably want to mock ITK implementations, but for a start I just want to make a function call that does depend on the actual library. Everything is running on x64, only I don't seem to be able to build the unit test project in x64, the configuration manager only allows for win32. I have set test>test settings>default processor architecture>x64, but that doesn't seem to help. When compiling I get:

```
...itk-4.8.1\x64\debug\include\itk-4.8\itkmathdetail.h(286): error C3861: '_mm_cvtsd_si64': identifier not found
```

When I look at project>properties>configuration properties>VC++ directories it says "...x86" all over the place, while in the project I'm trying to test it says "....x64".

How can I get this to work, please? Or am I on mission impossible???

**Update:**

I now managed to run the project with x64 settings. In this case I have the trouble that the unittest framework only runs on win32, hence:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CppUnitTest.h': No such file or directory
```

So...during compile-time I can choose whether my library doesn't compile (win32-mode) or the unit-test framework doesn't compile (x64-mode). A reminder: Compiling in win32-mode and setting test to "default processor architecture = x64" does not do the trick either, still compile errors described earlier. On that front, I have tried using a runsettings file, which made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found out where things went wrong. 1st of all everything has to be compiled in x64, also the unit test project. And if you make sure you follow these steps on how to set up a x64 project

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx

then you end up without trouble. However you need to make sure you copy win32 settings and DON'T tick "Create new solution platforms".